# DNS error after setting up mx record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I have my main domain *.myapp.com pointed at herokuapp (CNAME). This app lets users create their sub domains upon signup, eg s1.myapp.com. The idea is to let someone send an email to email@s1.myapp.com, the app will receive it, process it and list it a page for users of s1.myapp.com. Simple!

However, as soon as I set up an MX record for s1.myapp.com to mx.sendgrid.net,

I can no longer access the app at s1.myapp.com. DNS error!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Who is your DNS provider? Creating an alias/cname for the apex domain name is not supported by all DNS providers. Can you dump out a list of your DNS records for the domain?

Comment: Here's more info about pointing apex domains to heroku: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku/

No, I don't work for dnsimple but their service is awesome.

Comment: Hi, I got this resolved. Instead of setting an MX record for S1, I just had to add a wildcard mx to *.myapp.com

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved. Instead of setting an MX record for S1, I just had to add a wildcard mx to *.myapp.com